# Call manually fragment onCreateView

Tags: android, orientation, fragment

In my activity i'm using onConfigurationChanged when orientation is changing :

```
@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
 {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

     if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
     {
         Log.e(TAG,"onConfigurationChanged LANDSCAPE");
     }
     else
     {
         Log.e(TAG,"onConfigurationChanged PORTRAIT");
     }
 }
```

I want to refresh my fragment view, so ask the code to call onCreateView.
Is there any way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is :

In my abstract fragment class (extends from Fragment)

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    final View view = getView();

    ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {


        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) ARApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            populateViewForOrientation(inflater, (ViewGroup) getView());

            // Avoid infinite loop
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        }
    });
}

protected abstract void populateViewForOrientation(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup view);
```

Every instance of MyFragment have to implement the populateViewForOrientation() method :

```
protected void populateViewForOrientation(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    viewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    View subview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome, viewGroup);
    // do all the stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment has it's own [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) callback, so in Fragment do

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.root_layout, null);
    initView(inflater, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    final View view = getView();
    if (view != null) {
        initView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater(), (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.container));
    }
}

private void initView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup parent) {
    parent.removeAllViews();
    final View subRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
    parent.add(subRoot);
    //do all the stuff
}
```

Where the root_layout is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution doesn't redraw the view according to the orientation.

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade as the documentation says - it's up to you to handle onConfigurationChanged callback. Why not allow recreation then?

Comment: My problem is that when I turn the screen, I do not have to recreate the activity, but only the fragment.

Comment: When the screen is landscape, I have to inflate and display the landscape layout, etc.

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade why not allow re-create the activity and fragments then?

Comment: Because my boss said ;)

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade then just replace the root view. Updated the answer.